# Removing table tags and preserving <td> innerHTML in SharePoint list using JavaScript for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop, html-table, unwrap

I have a SharePoint list/table, i want to remove the all table tags or you can say unwrap all of my innerHTML inside all "td", so i can design the UI of that content. I have code, when i run this code it works a once, i want help to make some kind of for loop which will remove all the table tags and keep innerHTML of all "td"

```
/* Code Start */

var tableTags = document.querySelector('.ms-listviewtable td');

// get the element's parent node

var parent = tableTags.parentNode;

// move all children out of the element

while (tableTags.firstChild) parent.insertBefore(tableTags.firstChild, tableTags);

// remove the empty element

parent.removeChild(tableTags);

/* Code End */
```

JS Fiddle Link for Full Code:
https://jsfiddle.net/AzadKolachi/doh2j5wy/1/

Comment: Give us a proper [mre] including an example table, please, and specify what exact output/result you expect based on that.

Comment: you can my code on this link:
https://jsfiddle.net/AzadKolachi/doh2j5wy/

Comment: `document.querySelector('.ms-listviewtable td')` returns only the first matching table cell. You need to use `querySelectorAll`, and then loop over those cells.

Comment: Thanks for you help and logical answer but when i use queryselectorAll, It gives error in console that [caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'removeChild')]. Can some one help me to create this loop

Comment: `var parent = tableTags.parentNode;` - `tableTags` is not an element now, but a NodeList - and that NodeList does not have a `parentNode`. This needs to go _inside_ the loop over the list as well.

Comment: Nothing is working or maybe i am not a programmer so i cannot develop the logic to get the right code, could you please help me to achieve this

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5k48sr7a/ - but this way, all the content you remove from the table cells, will still be contained in the originating table row. And those again are still contained in the tbody, contained in the table. So you would actually have to put these elements several levels higher, than just appending them before their table cell. It would probably make more sense, if you appended them all to a new, empty container element, and then just remove the table afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove all the table tags and keep the innerHTML of all "td" elements in a SharePoint list or table, you can use a loop to iterate over all the "td" elements and unwrap their contents. Here's the modified code:

```
var tdTags = document.querySelectorAll('.ms-listviewtable td');

// Iterate over each "td" element
tdTags.forEach(function(td) {
  // Get the parent node
  var parent = td.parentNode;

  // Move all children out of the "td" element
  while (td.firstChild) {
    parent.insertBefore(td.firstChild, td);
  }

  // Remove the empty "td" element
  parent.removeChild(td);
});
```

This code uses the querySelectorAll method to select all the "td" elements
in the SharePoint list/table. Then, it iterates over each "td" element
using the forEach method. Inside the loop, it performs the same unwrapping
process as in your original code.

By running this modified code, it will remove the table tags and keep the
innerHTML of all "td" elements, allowing you to design the UI using the
extracted content.

Additionally, you can check out this code:

```
document.querySelector('.ms-listviewtable > thead').remove();

let rows = document.querySelectorAll('.ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr');

for (const row of rows) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        row.removeChild(row.firstElementChild);
    }
}

var tableTags = document.querySelectorAll('.ms-listviewtable td');

for (const td of tableTags) {
    var parent = td.parentNode;
    while (td.firstChild) {
        parent.insertBefore(td.firstChild, td);
    }
    parent.removeChild(td);
}
```